# postgresql query with time difference

Tags: postgresql

I have table structure as follows

```
id name point last_updated refresh_frequency
1 'abc' 100 2015-08-28 01:00:00 24
```

`last_updated` is datetime field and `refresh_frequency` is int

I want to get all rows which having last_updated  value before refresh_frequency (in Hours) from current time, How to write a query for this?

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE last_updated < NOW() - refresh_frequency * INTERVAL '1 hour';
```